# Unable to process add to cart button on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Currently making a shopping page for a school project using PHP. 
My code is vulnerable to SQL injections but it is okay, its part of a requirement of my project.
Current problem is that when I press "add to cart" button, I would just get a popup that said my cart is added, but it will update onto the database. This is my code called cart_process.php
mainpage.php is my main shopping cart page.

```
?php 
    session_start();
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbname="shopping";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if($conn->connect_error)
    {   
        die("Connect failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


$UserId= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['UserId']);
$burger= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['burger']);
$banana= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['banana']);
$mosquitotoy= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mosquitotoy']);
$spider= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['spider']);
$rabbits= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['rabbits']);
$tot_amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tot_amount']);
$tot_amount1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tot_amount1']);
$tot_amount2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tot_amount2']);
$tot_amount3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tot_amount3']);
$tot_amount4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tot_amount4']);

$sql= "INSERT INTO products (UserId, burger, banana, mosquitotoy, spider, rabbits, tot_amount, tot_amount1, tot_amount2, tot_amount3, tot_amount4)
VALUES ('$UserId','$burger','$banana','$mosquitotoy','$spider','$rabbits','$tot_amount','$tot_amount1','$tot_amount2','$tot_amount3','$tot_amount4' )";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($result)
    {
        $url=$_SESSION['url'];
        echo("<script language=''javascript'>
        window.alert('item added to cart successfully')
        window.location.href='https://easymoney.com/mainpage.php';
        </script>");
    }
else
    {

        $url=$_SESSION['url'];
        echo("script language='javascript'> window.alert('error adding to cart')
        window.location.href='https://easymoney.com/mainpage.php;
        </script>");
    }

?>
```

This is my database in PHP. I called it products. Burger, mosquitotoys, banana, spider and rabbits are items that I am selling. tot_amount stands for each of the price of the items respectively.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Feb 06, 2020 at 10:23 AM
-- Server version: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
-- PHP Version: 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.9

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `shopping`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `burger` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `banana` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `mosquitotoy` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `spider` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `rabbits` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `tot_amount` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `tot_amount1` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `tot_amount2` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `tot_amount3` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `tot_amount4` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `products`
--
ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `products`
--
ALTER TABLE `products`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: My code is vulnerable to SQL injections but it is okay, its part of a requirement of my project.

Comment: Instead of guessing what the problem might be, check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out the exact error.

Comment: You said you "get an error on the page" but you haven't told us what that error is.

Comment: You want it to be open to SQL injections? Interesting. My other recommendation for prepared statements is to eliminate quoting issues, so names like `O'Leary` or strings like `He's gonna blow!` won't break your query.

Comment: Ok currently, my page will have a pop up which will say item added to page!
It seems that I mistyped something earlier.
However, even with the pop up, it will not update into my database